# how to convert a sed regex to bbe?

Tags: sed

how to match/replace like this sed but in bbe:
`echo "abc894576def559872364abc23948572348576def" |sed -r "s@(abc[0-9]).*(def)@\1CCC\2@"`

because this does nothing:
`echo "abc894576def559872364abc23948572348576def" |bbe -e "s@(abc[0-9]).*(def)@\1CCC\2@"`

I need `bbe` because I need newline to be ignored, this also means I need "def" to be the 1st match and not the last one found in the binary file, like a delimiter, so my regex is also not good yet...

Comment: checked bbe's source code, no sign it ever uses regex. i think you could use perl instead

Comment: @don_aman `perl -i -w -0777pe 's/(abc[0-9])(.*?)(def)/$1CCC$3/sg' theBinaryFile` did the trick, thx vm!!! I had to use non greedy match `(.*?)` and it matched all in between begin/ending tokens with `/sg` and ignored all newlines `-0777`!

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `-r` option with your `sed`, so you are using GNU `sed` (`-r` is the GNU-only version of the `-E` option for `E`xtended regular expressions). So if all you want to achieve is to have the `.*` also cover newlines, use the `-z` option for GNU `sed` to use the zero byte instead of newline as delimiter:

```
sed -zE "s@(abc[0-9]).*(def)@\1CCC\2@"
```

For other `sed` versions, you'd need to get all lines in the pattern space like this:

```
sed -E "H;1h;$!d;x;s@(abc[0-9]).*(def)@\1CCC\2@"
```

That's collecting all lines in the hold space until the last line, then exchanging buffers to process the whole file at once. But beware the buffer size limits for large files.

The next problem is you want the first `def` match, so you'd need Perl's non-greedy match `.*?`, but you don't have that in `sed`, so you'd need to work around this using a character from which you know that it's not part of the file, let's say `#` for this example:

```
sed -zE "s@def@#@g;s@(abc[0-9]).[^#]*#@\1CCC#@;s@#@def@g"
```

By replacing the pattern with a single character, you can use the inverted match `[^#]` to match all characters except for the one you are looking for. If you are sure `def` exists, you can even drop the `#` at the end of the pattern and replacement.